# Oracle RDS (AWS): How to retrieve files generated?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Here's the situation, we have a store procedure that generates .txt files in a directory inside of a database. I recently migrated from Oracle DB SE on Linux to an RDS oracle database instance. 
I know I'm not able to access files remotely (no scp, or sftp) to copy the files that it generates, so instead of I decided to use DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE using a DB link to another database.

The link is working fine, but whenever I try to copy the file I get the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-19505: failed to identify file "/u01/test.txt"
ORA-27046: file size is not a multiple of logical block size
Additional information: 1
```

Is there any alternatives to do this without using an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

File size must be a multiple of 512 (or whatever you've set the logical block size to)

Ensure when the file is made that the size is exactly a multiple of 512, pad with zeros or similar to ensure this

See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=file-transfer